# Inserting Exception Message in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

My .Net C# Apllication Throws this run time Exception

```
'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')'
```

I have a Log in SQL Server DB, where I store the Exception Messages.
but when I try to insert the above error message,

```
INSERT INTO tblApplicationError ([ErrorDesc]) VALUES('Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')')
```

it gives me the below error

```
Incorrect syntax near 'value'
```

because of the single quote around the `'value'`. As the exception message was thrown at run time,
how do I Insert the message in DB

Comment: If you just need to escape a single quote, you have to double it, `INSERT INTO tblApplicationError ([ErrorDesc]) VALUES('Value cannot be null. (Parameter ''value'')') `

Comment: This question has been answered many many times before. Use a parameter.

Comment: @MaxXapi but the whole message is generated at runtime I cannot add one more single quote around the `' value'`

Comment: Like @DaleK said, you have to use a SQLParameter to avoid this problem (and it's a must practice btw)

Comment: [Back to basics: SQL Injection](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/back-to-basics-sql-injection/)

Comment: @DaleK The fact that it's possible doesn't mean it's a good idea. Personally, I see your last comment as an encouragement for bad practice, even though I'm sure you meant well.

Comment: @Prem, see [why parameters are a best practice](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE tblApplicationError(
ErrorDesc nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO tblApplicationError ([ErrorDesc]) VALUES('Value cannot be null. (Parameter ''value'')') 

SELECT * FROM tblApplicationError
```

See link: https://rextester.com/SYXD8392